# Is there anyway I can undo "Rejecting" a helpful suggested edit to my post?

Tags: discussion

On this post [how to check if period sign(.) is removed from the word in textbox in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917316/how-to-check-if-period-sign-is-removed-from-the-word-in-textbox-in-jquery) I got a notification there's a suggested edit and I thought it was one of those rubbish edits so I rejected it without reading it carefully, then I saw that it was a helpful edit and it really improves my answer in the way the OP needs.

The problem is that unlike regular reviewing, AFAIK approving/ rejecting/ improving suggested edits on *my own* posts doesn't need more reviews from other users to fully accept the action.

I've already included the edit within my answer and thanked the person who made the edit but still asking whether I can undo my review or not?

This is the review https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10972844

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users with [2K+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) can edit posts without needing them to be reviewed. Otherwise, the edit must be reviewed before it applies (by you or/and other users).

If I were reviewing the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10972844) you're referring, I would have rejected it for the reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Despite that fact that it *improves* your answer, it should have been a comment. I think that changing code (unless clear typos) should always be a suggestion and not actual edit.

For your question, you can't undo the review but you can see its revision and act the same way you did.

Comment: Thank you, the one who made the suggested edit has less than 1000 reputation, I totally agree it should of been within a comment but he didn't. so even edits on my own posts are still reviewed by others reviewers if the user who made the edit has less than 2000 reps?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Yes, they can approve or reject it.